# package org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.GlobalTemplateVariables does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I've got a minor problem and its becoming really tiring:

where do I put or find the org.eclipse package so that it becomes recognisable?

About my project: using swing, have 3 java files in 1 folder: main.java, database.java, mainframe.java, IntellijIdea IDE

```
package org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.GlobalTemplateVariables does not exist
```

Comment: The jar has to be put under the main folder and added to the classpath.

Comment: I fixed that. Now I have: package org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.GlobalTemplateVariables does not exist

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but why are you developing an app on IntelliJ that uses Eclipse's [JFace](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace)?

Comment: That class is part of JFace Text, you need an `org.eclipse.text_xxxxx.jar` (xxx is a release number)

Comment: [`org.eclipse.jface.text` can be found e.g. in Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.jface.text) (see also [ECentral](https://jmini.github.io/ecentral/)). [JFace](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace) is for SWT, not for Swing. Why are you limiting yourself by using IntelliJ. When using JFace consider to build your application on the Eclipse platform.

Comment: @greg-449 `org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.GlobalTemplateVariables` is probably in `org.eclipse.jface.text`, not in `org.eclipse.text`.

Comment: @howlger No, it is in the org.eclipse.text plug-in in Eclipse 4.23 despite the JFace package

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. I did not know that. Then it's https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.text in Maven Central.